# how to filter in angular2-tree

Tags: angular, tree, angular2-directives

I am trying to implement angular2-tree in my application, and its work great but when i try to add filter i am not able to figure out how to get the tree object which is used for filter.

here is link for angular2-tree docs https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/filtering

here is my html

```
<input #filter (keyup)="filterNodes(filter.value, tree)" placeholder="filter nodes" />
<Tree (onMoveNode)="onMoveNode($event)" [nodes]="nodes" [options]="customTemplateStringOptions"></Tree>
```

here is my ts code for filter

```
filterNodes(text, tree) {
   tree.treeModel.filterNodes("text", true);
};
```

but i am not able to get the tree object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input #filter (keyup)="filterNodes(filter.value, tree)" placeholder="filter nodes" />
<Tree #tree (onMoveNode)="onMoveNode($event)" [nodes]="nodes" [options]="customTemplateStringOptions"></Tree>
```

In you component code:

```
@ViewChild('tree') tree: any;
```

And then it should be defined in the component

Let me know if it solved your issue

Comment: here is the tree component https://rawgit.com/500tech/angular2-tree-component/master/example/webpack/dist/index.html

and i am trying to read the code from https://rawgit.com/500tech/angular2-tree-component/master/example/webpack/dist/main.bundle.js but there is no viewchild used

Comment: Do you get any error? can you please specify it here?